# Is there a way to add a resource to an UIElementCollection (like Grid.Children)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

in an XAML-File I have an Image defined as a resource. Of course I can assign it for instance as a content of a ContenControl (like a Button).
Is there a way in XAML to add such a resource to the Children of a Panel (like a Grid)

```
<!--Creation of the Image as a resource (in this case loaded from assembly ressources)-->
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Image x:Key="CheckImage" x:Shared="False" Margin="0" Stretch="None" Source="/CheckStyleRes;component/CHECK.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
...
<!--This is a workaround, putting the Image into an ContentControl and this into the Children-->
<Grid>
    <Grid.Children>
        <ContentControl x:Name="CheckMark" Content="{StaticResource CheckImage}"></ContentControl>
    </Grid.Children>
</Grid>
...
<!--But is there a syntax to add {StaticResource CheckImage} directly to Grid.Children-->
<Grid>
    <Grid.Children>
        <Image FromRessourceOrSomthingLikeThat= "{StaticResource CheckImage}">
    </Grid.Children>
</Grid>
```

I dont want an ImageSource as resource (then I could use the Source-Property of Image and create the Images in Children). My resource should be an ready to use Image. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could write

```
<Grid>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="CheckImage"/>
</Grid>
```

but you would usually not do that. It is not the typical way how child elements are added to their parents.

As noted in a comment below, you would not be able to set any attached property like `Grid.Row`, `Grid.Column`, `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Top`, `DockPanel.Dock` etc. on the child element, which makes the approach pretty useless.

---

Better declare a BitmapImage resource

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="CheckImage" UriSource="/CheckStyleRes;component/CHECK.png"/>
```

and add an Image like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="{StaticResource CheckImage}" Stretch="None"
           SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

If you don't want to repeat all the property assignments each time you declare an Image like this, move them into a default Image Style like

```
<Window.Resources>
    ...
    <Style TargetType="Image">
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: One thing to add is that using the `<StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="CheckImage"/>` approach, you cannot add any attached properties since the extension is not a `DependencyObject`. Therefore, you cannot even specify `Grid.Row`, which disqualifies it for most scenarios.

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive explanation. In my special case I dont need to set those attached properties (Two Images at the same position, which are switch between "Visible" and "Collapsed" via an VisualStateGroup and ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames). But I will use the way with Image.Source, it sounds more popular to me. 
I really wonder, why there are so much issueswith putting a resource into a ChildrensCollection. Assigning a Property like Image.Source by a resource is so easy.